# ajax call return list

Tags: ajax

I am making an ajax call

```
     $.ajax({
           url: urpath,
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'json',
           data: JSON.stringify(json),
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    },
           error: error
     });
```

The returning data is a list which has 2 columns. How do I iterate through the list and show the data. When I do alert(data) it just says object object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `for-in` loop:

```
for (var i in data){
  // data[i].something, etc
}
```

So here is how your code should be:

```
$.ajax({    
   url: urpath,
   type: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: JSON.stringify(json),
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (data) {
     for (var i in data){
      // data[i].something, etc
     }
   },
   error: error // assuming error is function
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If the JSON is indeed a list containing objects with 2 properties like this:

```
[{"prop1":"value1", "prop2":"value2"}, {"prop1":"value3", "prop2":"value4"}]
```

You could loop through them using the $.each method and inside the callback the `this` variable will point to each element in the list and you can access individual properties:

```
$.each(data, function() {
    alert('prop1=' + this.prop1 + ', prop2=' + this.prop2);
});
```